# Can a DFA have two symbols on one arrow?

Tags: terminology, automata, finite-automata

I know that a DFA has to have exactly one transition for each symbol in the alphabet, but is it allowed to have two symbols on the same arrow? If, for example, I have a DFA with states $q_0$ and $q_1$, can I have one arrow from $q_0$ to $q_1$ with both $a$ and $b$?

This may be a stupid question, but I need to be completely sure that this is allowed (I believe it is).

Comment: Yes. That's just the same thing as having two arrows, one labelled $a$ and one labelled $b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transition graph (as a drawing) is merely a representation of an Automaton, which is a well-defined model.

Formally, an DFA is a tuple $(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$, where the "type" of the transition function is $\delta:Q\times \Sigma\to Q$.

Thus, if you have $\delta(q_0,a)=\delta(q_0,b)=q_1$, that's fine.
In the graphic representation, you will either have two arrows from $q_0$ to $q_1$, labeled $a$ and $b$, or you can just put both letters on the same arrow, it's not a formal thing anyway.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the starting and ending  of respective states are same you can add as many symbols.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. An arrow by definition goes from one state to another state. How could an arrow not have the same start and end state *as itself*?

Comment: I've edited it as 'respective states'

Comment: I saw the edit. I still don't understand what you mean.